# Passing Hidden ID value to another page using javascript php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass hidden value from page to another page and it work fine only for first record however for other records it's showing error
Here is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,jdes,title FROM job";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_id" value="<?php echo  $row["id"]  ?>">
    <h3><?php echo  $row["title"]  ?>:</h3>
    <p class="lead">
      <?php echo  $row["jdes"]  ?> 
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="requestthis" class="btn btn-primary">
      <a href="jobs-inner.php">Request</a>
    </button>
    <?php

  }
} else {
  echo "Nothing to display Yet";
}
?>
```

jobs-inner.php

```
<?php  

echo $_GET['hidden_id'];

?>
```

Javascript:-

```
$(function() { //ready function
    $('#requestthis').on('click', function(e){ //click event
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var hidden_id = $('#hidden_user_id').val();
        var url = "jobs-inner.php?hidden_id="+hidden_id;

        window.location.replace(url);
    })
})
```

Error:-

```
 Undefined index: hidden_id in C:\wamp64\www\project\jobs-inner.php on line 3
```

It might be a simple problem but I am a beginner and I can't figure it out.

Comment: id attribute must be unique. its not with your case.

Comment: but id for each record is unique and i am getting it from database
i don't understand what you meant

Comment: id="hidden_user_id" check this. this remains for all record. only value will be changed not id

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes i think it is the problem can you help me out with the code too?

Comment: Can you put `console.log(hidden_id)` after `var hidden_id = $('#hidden_user_id').val();` and post the result here?

Comment: @SumanDey can you help me out with the code?

Comment: @31piy it's showing console empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value is unique but the id isn't. Make the id of the input unique something like below.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_<?php echo  $row["id"]  ?>" value="<?php echo  $row["id"]  ?>">
```

but you would have to do a count on code below to make it display base on how many rows you have.

```
<?php  
echo $_GET['hidden_id'];
?>
```

**Without JavaScript**

```
$sql = "SELECT id,jdes,title FROM job";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$count = 1;
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>

        <input type="hidden" id="hidden_user_<?php echo $count ?>" value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">
        <h3><?php echo  $row["title"]  ?>:</h3>
        <p class="lead"><?php echo  $row["jdes"]  ?></p>
        <form id="<?php echo $count ?>" action="jobs-inner.php?hidden_id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" method="post">
        <input type="submit" vaule="Request">
        </form>                     
        <?php
        $count++;  
        }
    } else {
        echo "Nothing to display Yet";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can't make it work it would b great if you elaborate it by using code